# A word for unhealthy and dirty lifestyle

Tags: synonyms

Can somebody help me with a word for unhealthy and dirty lifestyle.

Example: Colin is a rather obese boy, spends most his time playing video games and eating junk food. He follows such a _________ lifestyle.

Comment: @Rathony I mentioned unhealthy as well so I guess that covers up for being obese and yet eating junk food.

Comment: @Marv Mills looks better after the edit......thanks!! :)

Comment: @Josh61 - Why did you delete your answer?  I think it was better than the accepted one...

Comment: @ChrisSunami can you share the deleted answer?

Comment: @ChrisSunami - I thought it was too 'strong' for what OP is looking for, anyway it may help.

Comment: @user145880 I can't seem to see what is actually "dirty" in your example. I would go simply with "unhealthy lifestyle."

Comment: @user145880 At best, try "disgusting;" "distasteful," or even "repugnant' if you prefer; i.e. perceived as "dirty" to your senses, mind or morals. Like I said in my previous comment, I can't seem to see anything "dirty" in being obese, spending most of the time playing video games or eating junkfood...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without context it's hard to tell, but you might be thinking about a [**slob**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slob):

> (informal) A person who is lazy and has low standards of cleanliness:
>   *he’s a slob and expects others to clean up after him* (-- Oxford Dictionaries Online)

If you want a noun you can use *slobbishness*; an adjective for "lifestyle" would be *slobbish*.

Answer (score 16):

Consider **slovenly** as an alternative. [Link-MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slovenly) [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/182156)

OED describes it as:

> 2. Of a person or (occas.) an animal. Thesaurus »    a. Untidy, dirty; habitually careless, indolent, or negligent with regard to appearance,
>      personal hygiene, household cleanliness, etc.

Answer (score 5):

***[Dissolute](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissolute)*** is a term often associated to the lifestyle you are referring to:

> - used to describe someone (such as a person who often gets drunk) whose way of living is considered morally wrong.
> - lacking restraint; especially :  marked by indulgence in things (as drink or promiscuous sex) deemed vices, *the dissolute and degrading aspects of human nature*  Wallace Fowlie.

(M-W)